# How to get Date without Time from DateTime while join tables

Tags: c#, linq

I am joining three tables and I would like to get date without time.

```
var query = from anObjective in db.Objective
    join anObjectiveType in db.ObjectiveType 
               on anObjective.IdType equals anObjectiveType.IdObjectiveType
    join statusCode in db.StatusCode 
               on anObjective.IdStatusCode equals statusCode.IdStatus
    select new
    {
          IdObjective = anObjective.IdObjective,
          ObjectiveName = anObjective.ObjectiveName,
          DateCreation = anObjective.DateCreation, //get just Date without time
          DateEnd = anObjective.DateEnd,  //get just Date without time

    };
```

I know there is a method `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`, but it returns time with zero values. But I want to get just date without time.

I've also seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712208/returning-dates-without-times-in-a-linq-query), but I cannot figure out how to apply when joining, not grouping.

Model class:

```
public partial class Objective
{
    public int IdObjective { get; set; }
    public string ObjectiveName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreation { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateEnd { get; set; }    
}
```

**How to get Date value without time for properties such as  `anObjective.DateCreation` and `anObjective.DateEnd`?**

**My desirable result is just Date: 1.9.2016**

**Edit:**
*If I write  the following syntax:*

```
DateCreation =anObjective.DateCreation.Date,
//or
DateCreation =null ? default(DateTime?) :  anObjective.DateCreation.Date,
```

then I've got a such exception:

> 'System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for
>   'Date' and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'System.Nullable' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

*If I write:*

```
DateCreation =anObjective.DateCreation.Value.ToShortDateString(),
anObjective.DateEnd.Value.ToShortDateString(),
```

then I've got a such exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into
>   a store expression

*If I write:*

```
DateCreation =anObjective.DateCreation.Value.Date,
```

then  I've got a such exception:

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
>   Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties
>   are supported.

Comment: Have you tried using the `DateTime.Date` property? Not that you appear to be joining on `DateCreation` or `DateEnd`, btw...

Comment: have you tried putting '.Date' after your date selections?  e.g. anObjective.DateCreation.Date

Comment: @JonSkeet do you mean `public Nullable<System.DateTime.Date> DateCreation { get; set; }` in model class?

Comment: @StepUp: No, I mean using the `Date` property from the `DateTime` value you're getting. We didn't know the property was nullable, so it sounds like you might want `DateCreation = anObjective.DateCreation?.Date` etc.

Comment: @StepUp what is the data type for the DateCreation field?

Comment: @JonSkeet oops, Visual Studio 2013 :). There is no such syntactic sugar:).

Comment: @StepUp Hmm...how about .Value.ToShortDateString() from this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982303/get-short-date-for-system-nullable-datetime-datetime-in-c-sharp

Comment: Why not use IFormatProvider? Your date will be DateCreation = anObjective.DateCreation.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")

Comment: That should be in the question then... But you could use `anObjective.DateCreation == null ? default(DateTime?) : anObjection.DateCreation.Date` instead.

Comment: I mean `anObjection.DateCreation.Value.Date` for the RHS of the conditional operator. But basically it still boils down to my very first comment - you want the `DateTime.Date` property.

Comment: It doesn't help that the question now talks about `anObjective.Name`, which is a string, not a date/time value at all...

Comment: Whether name, date, string or integer, my answer has you covered... see *What am I thinking. A DateTime is just an integer. Subtract to midnight for both and they will equate* below

Comment: @StepUp try .GetShortDateSting, not .ToShortDateString.  You need to let Intellisense help out there.

Comment: @JonSkeet please, see my updated question. I've attached the exception I've got when I use `Date` property.

Comment: I don't see what really you are after - `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` is the EF query equivalent of `DateTime.Date` property which is unsupported. `DateTime.Date` also returns `DateTime` with zero time.

Comment: @IvanStoev I just want take date. For example, `1.5.2016` or `5.27.2016`

Comment: You **can't** take *date* in **DateTime** field. There is **no** date type in C# and .NET.

Comment: There is no Date datetype in .net without the hour.  You can use a formatter when you are presenting the value to hide the time part.

Comment: @JonSkeet  sorry for my lack of knowledge. I mislead you:)  sorry, guys. Upvoted for help!

Comment: @IvanStoev feel free to write an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: No problem mate, it happens. Thank you for the kind suggestion, really appreciate, but let move on - post and accept a self answer if you wish. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, recognize that there is no built-in type for a date without a time in .NET.  [At least not yet anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34751042/634824).  So if you want date-only, then you'll need it in a string in some particular format.

You're not going to be able to get the underlying provider of a LINQ query to understand the conversion of `DateTime` to `string`.  So, you'll need to query for the data in its original form, and *then* convert it to string after the query results are materialized.

Start with your original query, unmodified from what you showed at the top of your question.  Then add the following:

```
var results = query.AsEnumerable().Select(x=>
new
{
    IdObjective = x.IdObjective,
    ObjectiveName = x.ObjectiveName,
    DateCreation = x.DateCreation.ToShortDateString(),
    DateEnd = x.DateEnd.ToShortDateString()
});
```

You have some options also:

- If you know you want a `List` or an `Array`, then you can use `ToList()` or `ToArray()` instead of `AsEnumerable()`.
- If you want the resulting string to be in a specific format, or use a specific culture, then you can use `ToString` instead of `ToShortDateString`

For example, you might want an array containing a standard ISO-8601 date string and you might want to use the Invariant culture to avoid side effect when the current culture uses a non-Gregorian calendar system.

```
var results = query.ToArray().Select(x=>
new
{
    IdObjective = x.IdObjective,
    ObjectiveName = x.ObjectiveName,
    DateCreation = x.DateCreation.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DateEnd = x.DateEnd.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

add ".Date"

```
   anObjective.DateEnd.Date
   anObjective.DateCreation.Date
```

Comment: there is no such property. I mean `.Date`

Comment: anObjective.DateCreation.Value.Date ?

from the updates it looks like your DateTime is nullable<DateTime> so use .Value to get the DateTime and then .Date

carful with the null object reference, if there is no value!

Comment: thanks, I've tried. But the following exception is thrown `The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

Comment: now i see you actually solved it. getting the date with 0:00:00 as time IS actually just the date. C# uses the DateTime struct for Date as well as Date and Time. So this is basicly what you're going to find. is that not good? way do you need an object with no time (no time property, because as i said, the "zero" time should be ignored).

Comment: cause the date should be post to JavaScript and I do not want to format date in JavaScript

Comment: this is the DateTime struct. no getting around the object itself. if you send it to js via string you can write .ToShortDateString() and you'll get "12/09/2016"

Answer (score 1):

What am I thinking. A DateTime is just an integer. Subtract to midnight for both and they will equate.

```
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0);
int dateCreationInt = Math.Floor(dateCreation.Subract(epoch).TotalSeconds/86400);
int dateEndInt = Math.Floor(dateEnd.Subract(epoch).TotalSeconds/86400);
```

Or better yet:

```
 DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0);
int dateCreationInt = Math.Floor(dateCreation.Subract(epoch).TotalDays);
int dateEndInt = Math.Floor(dateEnd.Subract(epoch).TotalDays);
```

If you NEED a DateTime, simply re-convert the integers into datetimes - they will still equate to midnight and will thus be evaluated as "equal":

```
 dateEnd = epoch.AddDays(dateCreationInt);
 dateCreation = epoch.AddDays(dateEndInt);
```

Now, both dates will match if they are on the same date regardless of time.

**PUTTING IT ALL TOGETHER**

```
 DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1,1);
 select new
{
      IdObjective = anObjective.IdObjective,
      ObjectiveName = anObjective.ObjectiveName,
      DateCreation = epoch.AddDays(anObjective.DateCreation.Subtract(epoch).TotalDays),
      DateEnd = epoch.AddDays(anObjective.DateEnd.Subtract(epoch).TotalDays)

};
```

Comment: there is no such property. I mean `.Date`

Comment: MSDN says it's available (DATE) as of VS 2010.... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: thanks, I've tried. But the following exception is thrown `The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

Comment: What I've got: `'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Subtract' and no extension method 'Subtract' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Yeah - nullable kills it - you'd have to use regular datetime and convert to nullable before sending.

Comment: idk why you need nullable? a null value passed to a normal datetime yields a datetime with 1000 (or something). Just test on the other side for DateTime.Year<2000 and you've got your null fields.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need the .Value first since it's a nullable DateTime.  See this answer:

[Get short date for System Nullable datetime (datetime ?) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982303/get-short-date-for-system-nullable-datetime-datetime-in-c-sharp).

You should be able to grab the date formatted different ways than getshortdatestring afterwards.

Comment: thanks, I've tried. But the following exception is thrown `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: When you type .Value in VS, does Intellisense give you any choices or is it not recognizing it at all?  If it's a nullable DateTime, .Value should work.  Also, you need to check if the value is actually null in which case .Value will not work.

Comment: If I write `.Value`, then I've got `DateCreation = {5.05.2016 0:00:00}`. But I would like get just `5.05.2016 `

Comment: Right but after you type .Value, type another period (.) and see if you get some options from Intellisense.  I think you are basically there.

Comment: Try whatever returns what you want.  .Date?  .GetShortDateString?  It shouldn't be too hard to figure out the best one but I'm pretty sure there is an option (or more than one) to return just the date part of the datetime. Keep in mind that to get just the date, you are getting a string.  Oh, and that's GetShortDateString, not ToShortDateString as in your revised question.